# Determine Sequential vs Parallel execution proportions

Tags: haskell

Give some haskell program, is there any way in GHC to determine percentages of sequential vs. parallel execution time ratios? I am aware of `rtsopts` but as far as I'm aware that does not provide any details other than CPU-time and wall-time.

Comment: Just to make sure, you know about Simon Marlowe's book parallel and concurrent programming in haskell?

Comment: @epsilonhalbe yes I haven't read it though

Comment: Threadscope has the information necessary to figure this out, though I don't think it displays that particular bit of information. In any case, the [threadscope documentation](https://wiki.haskell.org/ThreadScope) should provide some pointers.